# Celery raise ImproperlyConfigured exception

Tags: python, celery

I am testing below case in Celery doc, but raise ImproperlyConfigured exception.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/calling.html#id3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "test.py", line 8, in <module> print(r.get(on_message=on_raw_message, propagate=False))   
File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py", line 189, in get on_message=on_message,   
File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 460, in wait_for_pending 'Backend does not support on_message callback')  
celery.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Backend does not support on_message callback
```

Test code is:

```
from celery_test.agent import hello
from celery_test.celery import app

def on_raw_message(body):
    print(body)

r = hello.apply_async(args=[122,34], queue='machine1', routing_key='machine1')
print(r.get(on_message=on_raw_message, propagate=False))
```

Output of celery -A celery_test report

```
[root@zm03 script]# celery -A celery_test report

software -> celery:4.0.0 (latentcall) kombu:4.0.0 py:2.7.9
            billiard:3.5.0.2 py-amqp:2.1.1
platform -> system:Linux arch:64bit, ELF imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:amqp results:amqp://guest@192.168.1.201//

CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE: 'direct'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER: 'json'
timedelta: <type 'datetime.timedelta'>
Exchange: <class 'kombu.entity.Exchange'>
CELERY_INCLUDE: ['celery_test.agent']
absolute_import: _Feature((2, 5, 0, 'alpha', 1), (3, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 16384)
Queue: <class 'kombu.entity.Queue'>
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES: 3600
CELERT_QUEUES:
    (<unbound Queue machine1 -> 'agent' -> machine1>,
 <unbound Queue machine2 -> 'agent' -> machine2>)
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT: ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER: 'json'
BROKER_URL: u'amqp://guest:********@192.168.1.201:5672//'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: u'amqp://guest@192.168.1.201//'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE: 'agent'
```

Comment: Can you please add `celery -A <project> report` output in question ?

Comment: @ssudake Already add the output of `celery -A <project> report`

Comment: I am not sure whether `on_message` callback is supported for rabbitmq backend. This seems to be recent change in celery code. Please have look [https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3477/files](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3477/files)

Answer (score 1):

rabbitmq result backend is removed in celery 5.x as it was deprecated in v4.x.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there seems to be some bug in celery. As `on_message` is supposed to work with `rabbitmq` backend.

Workaround: Move to `redis` for result backend.

Introduced during following pull request [[confirmation](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3477#issuecomment-262923783)],

https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/3477/files

I have created issue for bug you are facing,

https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3625

Answer (score 0):

in my case this conf is working well

````
CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://my_user:my_password@localhost:5672//```
````